# Let U be a uniform random variable on the interval (1; 5). Determine the probability density function of the following random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let U be a uniform random variable on the interval (1, 5). Determine the probability density
function of the following random variable:

Z = max(U,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here $Z$ is a partially continuous random variable. meaning that half of the time it will be constant 3 and the other half is equal to $U$. You can use Dirac delta function to model its density function.
$$
f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{2}\delta(z - 3) + \frac{1}{4} \quad\quad \text{for} \; 3\leq z \leq 5
$$